# How to extract a column of a DataTable into a ConcurrentQueue(Of T)?

Tags: .net, datatable

Suppose I have a small database represented in memory as a DataTable, what is the best way to extract a column from that DataTable and put it into a ConcurrentQueue(Of T)?

Or, should I use a different representation than a DataTable?

More details:

- The 'database' is an extract from a larger database, comprising just 3 columns and 100-200 rows.
- The ConcurrentQueue(Of T) will be consumed by a set of parallel tasks

#### Clarification:

Let's say the Data Table contains columns "A", "B", and "C", with rows 1 to 200. I need to create a ConcurrentQueue(Of T) containing the values from column "A" from *all* rows.

Comment: Column means you want 1 value of each row?  Please add some details.

Comment: @Henk I've clarified my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of relying on DataTables why don't you create a class to hold the data you require and add the functionality to the class (or class List) which will make more semantic sense.

Comment: That thought did cross my mind, but what about the overhead of marshaling the column values in and out of the 'collecting' class?

Comment: You mentioned 100-200 rows in your question. I can't imagine the overhead being a problem but if so that's obviously another issue.

Comment: hmm... you have a point there. shouldn't be more than an additional second or two, but worth it for future maintainability. thanks! I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: 2 seconds to process 200 records?? I would have thought nearer 5ms, or at least in the systems I develop that's what I would expect to see.

Comment: uh, I might have misconstrued myself there. my bad. what I meant to say was: *even if* such marshalling adds a second or two (which I'm sure it won't), I don't mind :)